# roscore crashing after automatic update

Tags: ros, roscore, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just *sudo apt-get updated* my **fuerte** installation and roscore now crashes.

Here is the message

```
auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [4443]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/bin/rosmaster", line 35, in <module>
    rosmaster.rosmaster_main()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ros_comm-1.8.12-py2.7.egg/rosmaster/main.py", line 73, in rosmaster_main
    configure_logging()   
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ros_comm-1.8.12-py2.7.egg/rosmaster/main.py", line 57, in configure_logging
    _log_filename = rosgraph.roslogging.configure_logging('rosmaster', logging.DEBUG, filename=filename)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ros_comm-1.8.12-py2.7.egg/rosgraph/roslogging.py", line 104, in configure_logging
    logging.config.fileConfig(config_file, disable_existing_loggers=False)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/config.py", line 78, in fileConfig
    handlers = _install_handlers(cp, formatters)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/config.py", line 153, in _install_handlers
    klass = _resolve(klass)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/config.py", line 94, in _resolve
    __import__(used)
ImportError: No module named RosStreamHandler
[master] process has died [pid 4443, exit code 1, cmd rosmaster --core -p 11311 __log:=/home/erupter/.ros/log/bce1000e-a11e-11e2-aa7b-e0cb4e8e9c06/master.log].
log file: /home/erupter/.ros/log/bce1000e-a11e-11e2-aa7b-e0cb4e8e9c06/master*.log
ERROR: could not contact master [http://FCD-04-Ubuntu:11311/]
```

Log files are all empty.

I tried removing and reinstalling ros but it didn't work.

Seen [this other question](http://answers.ros.org/question/59970/roscore-fails-to-start-after-latest-update-precise-groovy-amd64/) but it's the other way around for me and besides being on 12.04 LTS, I can't even do a dist-upgrade.

Also tried [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/54280/roscore-error/) (recreating the workspace) but it didn't do anything.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60304/roscore-crashing-after-automatic-update/) by [Claudio](https://answers.ros.org/users/3152/claudio/) on ROS Answers with karma: 859 on 2013-04-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

These are the (exact) same symptoms I experienced in groovy a few days ago ([see Q/A](http://answers.ros.org/question/59970/roscore-fails-to-start-after-latest-update-precise-groovy-amd64/)). Have you tried the "dist-upgrade" option?

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2013-04-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Claudio](https://answers.ros.org/users/3152/claudio/) on 2013-04-09**:
Tried, dist-upgrade won't do anything on my machine (I suppose 12.04 LTS can't be dist-upgraded until another LTS come out).

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-06-17**:
dist-upgrade does not change what distribution you are on.  It is simply a command which allows apt to install new dependencies, which is forbidden in a standard upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

looks similar to this question: [rostopic and other commands fail after update](http://answers.ros.org/question/59644/rostopic-and-other-commands-fail-after-upgrade)

---

Originally posted by [mthz](https://answers.ros.org/users/4610/mthz/) with karma: 66 on 2013-04-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Claudio](https://answers.ros.org/users/3152/claudio/) on 2013-04-09**:
No held upgrades here.

**Comment by [mthz](https://answers.ros.org/users/4610/mthz/) on 2013-04-09**:
have you tried manual "sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-rosgraph" ?

**Comment by [Claudio](https://answers.ros.org/users/3152/claudio/) on 2013-04-09**:
As I said I have to stay on fuerte. I'm working with Pandaboards and getting groovy on them has been nigh impossible.

**Comment by [inflo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4215/inflo/) on 2013-04-09**:
also the same as this un-answered thread http://answers.ros.org/question/60074/roscore-fails-to-start/